# How to merge DataFrame in for loop?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Am trying to merge the multiindexed dataframe in a for loop into a single dataframe on index.

i have a reproducible code at https://gist.github.com/RJUNS/f4ad32d9b6da8cf4bedde0046a26f368#file-prices-py
I wanted to post the code here, but i got an error 'your post has lots of code' therefore i posted it on gist.

But it produces this:

> ```
>                           CLOSE    HIGH    LOW    OPEN   VOLUME
> 2017-09-08 09:30:00 VEDL  330.2  330.40  328.3  329.10  1873261
> 2017-09-08 09:45:00 VEDL  333.1  333.15  329.5  330.15  1643970
> 2017-09-08 10:00:00 VEDL  332.4  333.20  331.4  333.10   767922
>                            CLOSE   HIGH    LOW    OPEN  VOLUME
> 2017-09-08 09:30:00 INFY  892.65  898.6  892.6  898.05  163020
> 2017-09-08 09:45:00 INFY  892.45  893.6  891.4  892.80  152179
> 2017-09-08 10:00:00 INFY  891.55  892.5  891.1  892.40  104931
> ```

Am expecting the following output:

> ```
>                           CLOSE    HIGH    LOW    OPEN   VOLUME
> 2017-09-08 09:30:00 VEDL  330.2  330.40  328.3  329.10  1873261
>                     INFY  892.65  898.6  892.6  898.05  163020
> 2017-09-08 09:45:00 VEDL  333.1  333.15  329.5  330.15  1643970
>                     INFY  892.45  893.6  891.4  892.80  152179
> 2017-09-08 10:00:00 VEDL  332.4  333.20  331.4  333.10   767922
>                     INFY  891.55  892.5  891.1  892.40  104931
> ```

I tried using `.join` method, but i couldn't make it work.
does anyone have any solution please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need append `df` to `list of DataFrames` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
dfs =[]
for security in stocks:
        dfs.append(get_google_data(security,900, 1))

df = pd.concat(dfs).sort_index()
print(df)
                           CLOSE    HIGH     LOW    OPEN   VOLUME
2017-09-08 06:00:00 INFY  892.65  898.60  892.60  898.05   163020
                    VEDL  330.20  330.40  328.30  329.10  1873261
2017-09-08 06:15:00 INFY  892.45  893.60  891.40  892.80   152179
                    VEDL  333.10  333.15  329.50  330.15  1643970
2017-09-08 06:30:00 INFY  891.55  892.50  891.10  892.40   104931
                    VEDL  332.40  333.20  331.40  333.10   767922
2017-09-08 06:45:00 INFY  891.10  891.55  889.55  891.55   282589
                    VEDL  332.10  332.80  331.30  332.40   384417
2017-09-08 07:00:00 INFY  890.90  891.60  890.25  891.10   119252
                    VEDL  332.15  332.70  331.65  332.05   345358
```

`List comprehension` version for create `list of DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.concat([get_google_data(x,900, 1) for x in stocks]).sort_index()
print(df)
                           CLOSE    HIGH     LOW    OPEN   VOLUME
2017-09-08 06:00:00 INFY  892.65  898.60  892.60  898.05   163020
                    VEDL  330.20  330.40  328.30  329.10  1873261
2017-09-08 06:15:00 INFY  892.45  893.60  891.40  892.80   152179
                    VEDL  333.10  333.15  329.50  330.15  1643970
2017-09-08 06:30:00 INFY  891.55  892.50  891.10  892.40   104931
                    VEDL  332.40  333.20  331.40  333.10   767922
2017-09-08 06:45:00 INFY  891.10  891.55  889.55  891.55   282589
                    VEDL  332.10  332.80  331.30  332.40   384417
2017-09-08 07:00:00 INFY  890.90  891.60  890.25  891.10   119252
                    VEDL  332.15  332.70  331.65  332.05   345358
```

Comment: Awesome man, that works.. but what if i need to drop NaNs from some row which could make `pd.concat` to not work, so can u please provide an example with `.merge` or `.join` or any other workaround if dimensions do not matches?

Comment: Not sure if understand your question - if need merge by index with list of dataframes `concat` is implemnted for this. Can you eplain more `NaN` problem?

Comment: suppose if `INFY` has 20 rows and `VEDL` has 15 rows, will `pd.concat` work? :)

Comment: Yes, sure. very nice. Now each MultiIndex has 2 `rows`, if merge `15` with `20` then get 15 pairs and 5 single rows (if same dates in both)

Comment: or you can try `reduce` with `merge`

Comment: @Wen it will be helpful for me as well as the community if you post your answer using `merge`, i will definetely upvote it, if it produces desired output as requested above. feel free, to post it.